# How to load a path independent image into python tkinter making the executable independent from the image path?

Tags: python, tkinter, icons, spyder

I am programming in `spyder 3.2.8`; `python 3.6` using `tkinter`. Set up my whole script and used pyinstaller to develop an application.

In my script I want to include the function `iconbitmap('')`. The problem is once I do this I specify an image path and when I develop the application it creates an error when I move the application to another PC.

I know why this error occurs. It is because the file path specified does not exist on the new PC.

I want to change the widget icon with that function. It works like I said in my script, but once I develop and transfer from one pc to another it can not find the image in question and hence creates the problem.

This is the specific part of the code I am trying to run:

```
window= tk.Tk()
window.title("Heating Requirement")
window.geometry("650x275")


window.iconbitmap(r'LOGO.ico')
```

As you can see it is simple but path dependent.

In my script it runs perfectly. 
The problem however is as stated above with the image being path dependent.

Is there a way to tell pyinstaller to change the iconbitmap instead of doing it in the script which makes it path dependent....

If you tell pyinstaller to change the application icon it is not path dependent as it incorporates the image to the build. I want pyinstaller to incorporate the iconbitimage to the build as well.

Is there perhaps an external way to change the iconbitimage. Meaning outside of the script?

Is there a way to permanently change the iconbitimage in tkinter?

Comment: Would putting them in a fixed location relative to the script be an option?

Comment: @FlyingTeller The aim is to use the program on multiple computers Hence there is no fixed location.

Comment: The key is the term relative. The absolute path can change, so long as you have a fixed relative path to the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it figured out a couple months back just forgot to post the answer:

First step: Write in the script::

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
#""" Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

image_path = resource_path("LOGO.ico")

window= tk.Tk()

window.iconbitmap(image_path)
```

Seconly: Run the finished script through pyinstaller and let it create a spec file (in cmd opened in the same window as your .py and .spec file):

```
pyinstaller.exe -f -F program_name.py
```

Third: Locate the created program_name.spec file below you program_name.py script and open the program_name.spec with NotePad.

Fourth: Now copy and paste below info into spec file and change necessary info.

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
a = Analysis(['C:\\Users\\Aston
\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\Scripts\\program_name.py'],
                 pathex=['C:\\Users\\Aston 

\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\Scripts'],
                 hiddenimports=[],
                 hookspath=None)
    a.datas += [ ('image_name.ico', 'C:\\Users\\Aston
\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\Scripts\\Image_name.ico', 'DATA')]

pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name=os.path.join('dist', 'What ever you want to name program.exe'),
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=False , icon='C:\\Users\\Aston\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\Scripts\\image_name.ico')
```

Remember to save the spec file.

Fifth: Now run pyinstaller again but this time use (in cmd opened in the same window as your .py and .spec file):

```
pyinstaller.exe -f -F program_name.spec
```

Comment: bro you are a lifesaver

Answer (score 1):

Say you have your app in

```
/home/aston/app/script.py
```

then you could put the image into

```
/home/aston/app/images/foo.png
```

and reference it from the script as

```
import os
dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
os.path.join(dirname, "image", "foo.png")
```

which will take the path to the current script and append `image/foo.png`

Now say you copy it to your friend bob's computer and now have

```
/home/bob/app/script.py
```

and

```
/home/bob/app/image/foo.png
```

The image is still in the path `image/foo.png` **relative** to the location of `script.py` hence the path build in the script will still be correct

Comment: That could work yes. But there is always the chance of someone deleting the additional folder containing the image. Hence making the program defective.

Comment: But that is true for any program. If you go into `C:/Program files/` and start deleting stuff, then there is no suprise if some of your programs do not work anymore

Comment: Yes. But I want to know if there is a way to generate the image in the program build instead of running it in a relative file

Comment: So you are looking for the `pyinstaller` option `--add-data`?

Comment: If I create a shortcut to Desktop, its no more useful