# Trying to import image that's not path dependent in Tkinter

Tags: python, image, tkinter, path, python-imaging-library

The images are doing just fine in my device but of course it won't appear on other device. Because the images are still path dependent.

So i've tried doing like what the answer on this question says
[How to load a path independent image into python tkinter making the executable independent from the image path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52646089/how-to-load-a-path-independent-image-into-python-tkinter-making-the-executable-i)

And writing it down like this

```
dir_lion = os.path.dirname(__file__)
os.path.join(dir_lion, "image", "lion.jpeg")
image_lion = Image.open(dir_lion)
image_lion_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_lion)

label_image_lion = ttk.Label(main_frame, text='lion', image=image_lion_tk)
```

But it doesn't work and give out this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PATH", line 81, in <module>
    image_gol = Image.open(dir_gol)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "PATH", line 3243, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: "PATH"
```

(n). PATH = the file path

Comment: The error traceback does not match the posted code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you are trying to open a folder (`dir_lion`), rather than a file. This likely leads to the `PermissionError` you get (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36434764/17278075)).

Try:

```py
image_path = os.path.join(dir_lion, "image", "lion.jpeg")
image_lion = Image.open(image_path)
```

Maybe your were assuming that `os.path.join()` works in place? Well, it does not... have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

Hope this helps!